# fast blur image with integral image (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv

i like to blurring a image with opencv integral image. I just found a example from here:

[Fast Blur Image](http://www.quasimondo.com/IntegralImageForCanvas/IntegralImageBlurDemo.html)

How could i do this with opencv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [cv::blur()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#cv-blur):

```
void cv::blur(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, Size ksize, Point anchor=Point(-1, -1), int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT)
```